# Numpy Slicing slow?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, numba

Hi I am running scientific computing using numpy + numba.
I've realized that numpy array addition in-place is very slow... compared to matlab

here is the matlab code:

```
tic;
% A,B are 2-d matrices, ind may not be distinct
for ii=1:N 
    A(ind(ii),:) =  A(ind(ii),:) +  B(ii,:);
end
toc;
```

and here is the numpy code:

```
s = time.time()
# A,B are numpy.ndarray, ind may not be distinct
for k in xrange(N):
     A[ind[k],:] += B[k,:];
print time.time() - s
```

The result shows that numpy code is 10x slower than matlab... which confuses me a lot.

Moreover, when I pull the addition out of for loop, and just compare a single matrix addition with numpy.add, numpy and matlab seem to be comparable at speed.

One factor I know is that matlab uses JIT for version>=2012a to speed up for loop, but I tried numba on python code, it still does not speed up even a bit. I think this has to do with that numba has not touched numpy.add function at all, hence the performance does not change at all.

I am guessing that matlab does some sick caching for this case, hence it beats numpy dramatically.

Any suggestion on how to speed up numpy ?

Comment: Please add sample input data `A`, `B`, and `ind`. You can do this by generating random data of the correct shape. Without this, answering your question is largely guesswork.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
A[ind] += B[:N]
```

i.e. without any loop.

If `ind` could have duplicate elements, you can use [`np.add.at`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html):

```
np.add.at(A, ind, B[:N])
```

Comment: Thanks, but the elements in ind are not distinct.
Say ind = [1,2,4,1,2]; Than your code will actually produce different result to the version of for-loop.

Comment: Good point. I didn't spot that. This example is mentioned in [the documentation](http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-0dffc419afa7d77d51062d40d2d84143db8216c2), will have a think about what can be done

Comment: Please add data to your post and people will be able to help more. Otherwise see Robert Kern's suggested method here: http://numpy-discussion.10968.n7.nabble.com/Incrementing-with-advanced-indexing-why-don-t-repeated-indexes-repeatedly-increment-td26288.html

Comment: Including the `bincount` solution in your answer would be quite helpful.

Comment: got it and done !! it is indeed very helpful. However it seems that bincount only support 1-d array, not matrix. That's enough though. Thanks.

Comment: @Jing You may want to consider downloading numpy 1.8, it should support fancy indexing for ufuncs. Operations like `arr[[0, 1, 2, 2]] += 1` work as expected and increment `arr[2]` twice.

Comment: @Ophion: No, that behavior didn't change. The change was that they added the new [`at` method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) for ufuncs, which does what people initially expect `arr[duplicate_indices] += stuff` to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here'a version that uses dot matrix multiplication.  It constructs a matrix of 1s and 0s from `ind`.

```
def bar(A,B,ind):
    K,M =B.shape
    N,M =A.shape
    I = np.zeros((N,K))
    I[ind,np.arange(K)] = 1
    return A+np.dot(I,B)
```

For a problem with sizes like `K,M,N = 30,14,15` this is about 3x faster.  But for larger ones like `K,M,N = 300,100,150` it's a bit slower.